# This piece of code is iterating through the vector &path and only returning memory address rather than the actual value. I have tried using & and *

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, memory-address

```
void GraphTraversal::printPath(std::vector<const Node *> &path)
{
    cout << "START: ";
    for (auto it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << "->";
    }
    cout << "END" << endl;
};
```

This is the output START: 0x7ffe7bcd63b0->0x7ffe7bcd63b0->0x7ffe7bcd63b0->0x7ffe7bcd63b0->END

The Node class has two private variables

```
int nodeID;
std::set<const Edge *> outEdges;
```

To access these, there are two public functions

```
int getNodeID() const { 
    return nodeID; 
}

// Get the private attribute outEdges 
std::set<const Edge *> getOutEdges() const { 
    return outEdges; 
}
```

I have tried the following code to access the nodeID, but it doesn't work as well

```
it->getNodeID();
```

Comment: try to use (*it)->getNodeID();

Comment: When you dereference the iterator (`*it`) you get a pointer, which you have to dereference *again* to get the Node.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating the reason @BoP

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
   public:
      int a;
   A(int a){
      this->a = a;
   }
};

int main()
{
   vector<A*> vec1;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
      vec1.push_back(new A(i));
   }
   for (auto it = vec1.begin(); it != vec1.end(); it++){
      cout << (*it)->a << " ";
   }

   return 0;
}
Output : 0 1 2 3 4
```

I hope this gives you a clue. Since you have a pointer in your vector you need to dereference it as well. 
So you need to use `(*it)->getNodeID()` as Nikolay Fomichev sugessted.